# Sums over primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

I know that
$$\sum_{p \leqslant x} \frac{\log p}{p} \sim \log\log x$$

Do we know something explicit with the additional congruence condition (which makes the assumption on $x$ maybe useless, but I am interested in letting $q$ grow)
$$\sum_{\substack{p \leqslant x \\ p | q}} \frac{\log p}{p}$$

And more generally, for other $s$, what can be said of
$$\sum_{\substack{p \leqslant x \\ p | q}} \frac{\log p}{p^s}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The sum you're considering is finite for every $q$. I'm probably missing the point.

Comment: @PITTALUGA Yes, my question indeed is: what can be said about it as a function of $q$?